# Coldfusion 2016 API Manager not coming up after restart

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, coldfusion-2016

I'm running api manager on linux machine. I did restart and now it's not coming up again. I am keep getting following error related to redis server. I did restart several times but still same error. All Add-on is locally installed in the same machine. Any idea what's going on?

```
    [ERROR] 2019-11-10 20:27:07.635 [main] GrootServer - Unable to start Config service. Please refer apimanager-exception.log for more details.
com.adobe.amp.spi.ServiceException: Unable to start Config service. Please refer apimanager-exception.log for more details.
    at com.adobe.amp.GrootServer.startService(GrootServer.java:318) ~[apim-core.jar:?]
    at com.adobe.amp.GrootServer.initializeAndStartService(GrootServer.java:327) ~[apim-core.jar:?]
    at com.adobe.amp.GrootServer.startConfigService(GrootServer.java:290) ~[apim-core.jar:?]
    at com.adobe.amp.GrootServer.startAllServices(GrootServer.java:161) ~[apim-core.jar:?]
    at com.adobe.amp.GrootServer.start(GrootServer.java:116) [apim-core.jar:?]
    at com.adobe.amp.GrootServer.main(GrootServer.java:397) [apim-core.jar:?]
Caused by: com.adobe.amp.spi.ServiceException: Not able to connect to Datastore service.
    at com.adobe.amp.DefaultConfigurationPopulator.readDefault(DefaultConfigurationPopulator.java:104) ~[apim-config.jar:?]
    at com.adobe.amp.DefaultConfigurationPopulator.populateDefaultConfig(DefaultConfigurationPopulator.java:63) ~[apim-config.jar:?]
    at com.adobe.amp.ConfigServiceImpl.loadDefaultSetting(ConfigServiceImpl.java:234) ~[apim-config.jar:?]
    at com.adobe.amp.ConfigServiceImpl.startService(ConfigServiceImpl.java:107) ~[apim-config.jar:?]
    at com.adobe.amp.spi.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:47) ~[apim-spi.jar:?]
    at com.adobe.amp.GrootServer.startService(GrootServer.java:313) ~[apim-core.jar:?]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.adobe.amp.spi.redis.RedisException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at com.adobe.amp.redis.RedisServiceImpl.handleCommand(RedisServiceImpl.java:229) ~[apim-config.jar:?]
    at com.adobe.amp.redis.RedisServiceImpl.getSet(RedisServiceImpl.java:868) ~[apim-config.jar:?]
    at com.adobe.amp.DefaultConfigurationPopulator.readDefault(DefaultConfigurationPopulator.java:102) ~[apim-config.jar:?]
    at com.adobe.amp.DefaultConfigurationPopulator.populateDefaultConfig(DefaultConfigurationPopulator.java:63) ~[apim-config.jar:?]
    at com.adobe.amp.ConfigServiceImpl.loadDefaultSetting(ConfigServiceImpl.java:234) ~[apim-config.jar:?]
    at com.adobe.amp.ConfigServiceImpl.startService(ConfigServiceImpl.java:107) ~[apim-config.jar:?]
    at com.adobe.amp.spi.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:47) ~[apim-spi.jar:?]
    at com.adobe.amp.GrootServer.startService(GrootServer.java:313) ~[apim-core.jar:?]
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. It looks like config.xml had different redis server address. I updated it back to local 127.0.0.1 and Bingo it works.
Stupid thing is even though you run ./apimanger start skipaddon. It is still trying to validate redis server